# jquery.load() function not calling the jquery in embedded file

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have 2 html files : test1 and test2

test1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"/></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


   $('#content').empty().load('test2.html');

});


</script>


</head>

<body>
<div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

test2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"/></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


  alert(202);

});

</script>


</head>

<body>
test
</body>
</html>
```

When I run test1 it only shows "test" and not the alert.So it cannot take in the embedded jquery. So how can I make it take? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The [load function](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback) always filters out everything from the referenced HTML except the body element on load.  Try moving your script into the body element and see if that helps.

> In jQuery 1.2 you can now specify a
>   jQuery selector in the URL. Doing so
>   will filter the incoming HTML
>   document, only injecting the elements
>   that match the selector. The syntax
>   looks something like "url #some >
>   selector". Default selector "body>*"
>   always applies. If the URL contains a
>   space it should be escape()d. See the
>   examples for more information.

Note that you can apply a selector on load that does more extensive filtering as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the script into the `<body>` on the page that you are loading.

Aleternatively, you might consider using the callback of the `load()` function to show the alert

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#content').empty().load('test2.html', function() { alert(202); });

});
```